# Show/Hide Keyboard on the Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: keyboard, samsung-galaxy-s-2, htc-magic, keyboard-shortcuts

I used to have a HTC Magic, and I recently switched to a Samsung Galaxy S2.

One thing I miss is the ability to Show/hide the keyboard, on the HTC Magic, a long press of the menu key toggled the keyboard's visibility, is there a way to achieve the same thing on the Galaxy S2?
(I tried several long presses and various swype up or down gestures to no avail...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posted my question too quickly, I just found a way to do a bit the same, when the keyboard is out, a press on back will hide it, this is handy when filling forms with numerous entries, to make the keyboard pop out again simply click in a text field...

This is enough so far, and a long press on the menu will bring out the search window.